# CSS Inline align

Tags: layout, css

Trying layout inline elements I discover wierd behavior.
Can someone explain me why is there any different?

To both HTML I apply this css:

```
.time {
    position: relative;
    top:100px;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.time > .snapshot {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:2px;
    height: 13px;
    top: -5px;
    background: red;
}
.time:after {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And now HTML
- Wierd behavior:

```
<div class="time" >
    <div class="snapshot" ></div><div  class="snapshot" ></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSLAJ/

- Expect behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/dXwjR/1/

**Update**

I play a little with inline-block and justify, and I have another wierd example:

```
<div style="text-align: justify;">
    test test test
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">test test</div>
    test test test
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQbx7/)

I just wonder why second anonymous inline element is not justify?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the fact that inline elements are sensitive to white space in the code, and that's what's providing the spacing in your "expected" example. Add some `margin-right` to your `.snapshot` tick marks in your other one and they'll spread out like the other example.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FSLAJ/2/)**

Comment: Yeap you right white spaces this what give the justify effect. I just wonder way justify not treat divs with inline-block as separated and able to justify elements. It looks like justify just work on white spaces period.